# Using backbone, take dates as input and sort the data accordingly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection and model, and 'effdate' as one of the input in the displayed grid. I would like to get a starting 'effdate' and ending 'effdate' as an input and sort the grid within those dates and display and then return to default page.

'Effdate' is of type date looking like 02/01/2012 as an input.

What's the best way to handle such a filter?

Thanks

Comment: Is the question about how to you sort collections or how to sort based on dates?

Comment: Yeah sort data based on dates as filter.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to attack this. You can parse the date strings, then apply sorting on each section of the date - the challenge here is the date can only always appear in one format. The second strategy is just to instantiate a new Date object for each date, call getTime on the object, and sort the resulting values from that call.

Comment: Would the latter strategy work if say I have more than one date columns to search for like 'effdate','transdate' and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Backbone collections have a property [comparator](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Collection-comparator) that sorts the collection everytime a model is added, or you can call [sort](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Collection-sort) to force the re-sort. That triggers a sort event that you can use it to update the view.

If you want to use different fields to sort it at different times you can create a comparator that uses the field you want to use

```
var Book = Backbone.Model;
var books = new Backbone.Collection;

var sortField = "transdate";

var comparator = function (book) {
    return book.get(sortField);
};

var negativeComparator = function (book) {
    return (-1 * book.get(sortField));
};
books.add(new Book({
    title: "one",
    effdate: new Date("02/01/2012"),
    transdate: new Date("03/01/2019")
}));
books.add(new Book({
    title: "two",
    effdate: new Date("02/01/2013"),
    transdate: new Date("03/01/2017")
}));
books.add(new Book({
    title: "three",
    effdate: new Date("02/01/2014"),
    transdate: new Date("03/01/2015")
}));
books.comparator = comparator;
sortField = "effdate";
books.sort();


alert(books.pluck("title"))
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Markinhos/6nhcH/) is a jsFiddle to test it.

Comment: Pretty much the same question as above...would writing one comparator work if I have more than one column to search for...And how?

Comment: I don't know i might not be well equipped to understand this right.But a follow up question. I see that you have used 'effdate' as one of the dates column and it might work. But what about if I have 'effdate', 'transdate' and couple of more dates column like that. Would I have to write that comparator method again and again? Or is there still an efficient way to cover those columns in a single comparator method?

Comment: I may not understand the question. You have a grid with multiple columns and you want to sort the underlying collection based on the column you select, is that it?

Comment: Yeah. So  i have multiple columns of dates. And I want an option to search through the grid with one of those options at a time.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. I have updated the code and added a jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I used 'Pikaday' source, it's js datepicker and it's very useful. So now if I have to even go ten years ago to fetch a data, supposedly. I can use this resource. It's on github, if you want to check it out.